# How to filter array of objects by object property in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to print out the movies that have time sessions that start after the hour 20 or the same day. Either way, I can't get it to work.

Component data structure:

```
day:"2017-06-08T18:34:27.211Z"
movies:Array[8]
0:Object
   Description:"orphan the becomes a famous magician "
   id:1
   movieName:"Harry Potter "
   time_session:Array[3]
     0:Object
       id:1
       pivot:Object
       time:"2017-06-14 00:00:00"
     1:Object
     2:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
```

Template:

```
<template>
  <div> 
    <li v-for="movie in filteration(movies)">{{movie.movieName}}</li>
  </div>
</template>
```

How can I filter the movies so that the movies displayed depend on the time sessions in that same Object?

Here's what I've tried:

```
<script>
  export default{
    data() {
      return {
        movies:[],
        day:moment()
      }
    },  
    mounted(){
      axios.get("/fa")
        .then(response  => this.movies = response.data);
    },
    methods:{
      filteration(movie){
        return movie.filter(this.time);
      },
      time(movie){
        return moment(movie.time_session.time).hour() > 20;
        // return moment(movie.time_session.time).isSame(this.day,'day');
      }    
    }
  }     
</script>
```

Comment: "time sessions that starts after 20 or the same day" After twenty what? What are time sessions? Can you explain more in depth what the filtering conditions are?

Comment: every movie has time sessions, as you see time session is an array contains objects each with different date and time, so I want to print out the movies only that correspond to my filtration conditions. here I want it to be the time or the date...hope I could explain

Comment: 20 as in 8PM I expect.

Comment: yes, and it doesn't work and when I use the same day condition also. my code needs to be corrected somehow..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely reason you're having issues is that you are passing `movie.time_session.time` to `moment`. But, `movie.time_session` is an array of sessions and doesn't have a `time` property. You probably need to compare to the time of each element of the `time_session` array.

Generally, the best way to display an array of filtered data in Vue is to make a computed property that filters the data and returns it.

In your case you can make a computed property `filteredMovies` that returns the filtered movies and use that in your template instead:

```
computed: {
  filteredMovies() {
    return this.movies.filter((movie) => { 
      return movie.time_session.reduce((acc, session) => {
        return acc || (moment(session.time).hour() > 20);
      }, false);
    });
  }
}
```

Then, in your template, reference `filteredMovies` like so:

```
<li v-for="movie in filteredMovies">{{movie.movieName}}</li>
```